# WP Job Manager: Creating a custom job search form

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to have a search field on my homepage with the WP Job Manager Plugin.

from the functionality point of view it should be like on AirBnB but without the checkin/checkout/guest option and instead a simple search field some check boxes  like this

and there should be a "Search" button which would than link to the page where the search results are presented.

There is a tutorial (https://wpjobmanager.com/document/tutorial-creating-custom-job-search-form/, but I do not Understand it.

Would appreciate any answer!

The following code is my "job-filters.php"-file, where I edited the search field.

```html
<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-job-manager-ajax-filters' ); ?>

<?php do_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_before', $atts ); ?>

<form class="job_filters">
 <?php do_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_start', $atts ); ?>

 <div class="search_jobs">
  <?php do_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_search_jobs_start', $atts ); ?>

  <div class="search_keywords">
   <label for="search_keywords"><?php _e( 'Search', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></label>
   <input type="text" name="search_keywords" id="search_keywords" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Search', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $keywords ); ?>" />
  </div>



  <?php if ( $categories ) : ?>
   <?php foreach ( $categories as $category ) : ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="search_categories[]" value="<?php echo sanitize_title( $category ); ?>" />
   <?php endforeach; ?>
  <?php elseif ( $show_categories && ! is_tax( 'job_listing_category' ) && get_terms( 'job_listing_category' ) ) : ?>
   <div class="search_categories">
    <label for="search_categories"><?php _e( 'Category', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></label>
    <?php if ( $show_category_multiselect ) : ?>
     <?php job_manager_dropdown_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category', 'hierarchical' => 1, 'name' => 'search_categories', 'orderby' => 'name', 'selected' => $selected_category, 'hide_empty' => false ) ); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
     <?php job_manager_dropdown_categories( array( 'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_category', 'hierarchical' => 1, 'show_option_all' => __( 'Any category', 'wp-job-manager' ), 'name' => 'search_categories', 'orderby' => 'name', 'selected' => $selected_category, 'multiple' => false ) ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
   </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php do_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_search_jobs_end', $atts ); ?>
 </div>

 <?php do_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_end', $atts ); ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'job_manager_job_filters_after', $atts ); ?>

<noscript><?php _e( 'Your browser does not support JavaScript, or it is disabled. JavaScript must be enabled in order to view listings.', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></noscript>
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Please share the code.

Comment: Thank you for replying so quickly! Just added the (hopefully) relevant code snippet. When I insert "[jobs]" as a shortcode, this will be displayed.

Comment: you havent said whats wrong with your code, Q's asked in the manner fix this for me, i cant .... dont really do well here. try a few echos, google function names to see what you can understand and achieve on your own and ask here if you have a issue with a specific code issue rather than a whole project you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi David, I think this tutorial https://wpjobmanager.com/document/tutorial-creating-custom-job-search-form/ is what would help me, but I do not get where I "add a custom template file", so if anyone could explain this tutorial a bit more, would help me a lot!

Comment: google wordpress page hierarchy, it will tell you what to call your files in relation to different post types. If it is a page post type, you can select the template from the post edit screen, page templates are usually called page-yourname.php but they need the vital header comment code stating the template name (google page post template or see any themes page templates). templates are added in your active theme or child theme. Btw if commenting on your own post, its best to reference the person you are addressing with `@david` this way i get notified of your response.

Comment: thank you a lot, @David ! I will try your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I've just done this, you paste that code example where you would like the search boxes to appear.

For me, it was on my homepage in the hero banner. This sets up the form. like so:

[image]

I haven't styled it yet.

To get it working you need to change this line in the example code to show the url where your main jobs page is:

```
<form method="GET" action="YOUR_JOBS_PAGE_URL">
```

For me it was:

```
<form method="GET" action="../all-jobs">
```

When you set up WP Job Manager, it asks you to choose a page where you will display the jobs - then you add the relevant shortcode to that page and that page will display all of your jobs.

This page is the page you need to add inside that line of code. The page I chose was called all-jobs and appeared at the end of my URL like this: http://www.synergy-personnel-services/all-jobs/

I believe you can, of course, put the full URL in there, but adding just the name of the page preceded by the ../ ensures if you ever change the domain the link will still work

Comment: It works for me, after search the keyword disappears from the search field. It would be better if it stays there.